# Cannot read long filenames in Gpg / Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, gnupg

I have some deeply nested directories on Windows 10.  I had to use the following setting in git:

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

I now started having problems with the GPG plugin.  I can do a mvn install if I move the project directly to my C: drive.

```
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.6:sign (sign-artifacts) @ xxxxxxxxxxxx.jar ---
gpg: can't open `C:\\Users\\name\\workspace\\xxxxx_xxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\target\\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jar': No error
```

Comment: Long paths in windows can break many things. Move your project into higher level..There is a limitations...which only Microsoft could solve not Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved the whole project to the root directory.  From the comment above, there doesn't seem to be much else I can do.